# omnet ++ program and when executing this message appears error in module( cModule )

Tags: omnet++

Hello I having trouble implementation a project on the omnet ++ program and when executing this message appears:

> error in module( cModule ) network .server (id=4)during network setup:
>   submodule udp App: no module type named my node app